# What does "int&& a = something;" in C++ means?

Tags: c++, integer

I see at many places the fastest solution to a problem(often complex ones) sometimes have this line -

"int&& a = something;"

what does it really mean?
To test, i tried "int&& a = 5;" against "int b = 5;", and both a and b print same value 5.
However, in disassembly, i see -

```
void function() {
    int&& a = 5;
    int b = 5;
}
```

as

```
1 function():
2        push    rbp
3        mov     rbp, rsp
4        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 5
5        lea     rax, [rbp-16]
6        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
7        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 5
8        nop
9        pop     rbp
10       ret
```

(lines 4, 5, 6 to int&&)
3 line instructions against 1.
So, what operations is it performing, and how does it makes code faster?

Searched int&& online, but could not find any reference, simple example explaining this.

Comment: Those are "rvalue references". Completely pointless in this case though, `int &&a = 5;` ends up being effectively the same as `int a = 5;`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Searching "rvalue references" quickly showed some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a type different from your commonly seen single-ampersand *lvalue reference*, called an **rvalue reference**.

It's used when an expensive deep-copy operation is unnecessary and could be better optimized with move semantics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors